# Unit-Testing a WooCommerce Extension

Tags: wordpress, unit-testing, woocommerce, phpunit

I'm new to using PHPStorm along with PHPUnit, and the wordpress-develop package.

My projects rely on WooCommerce a lot.

Is it possible to add it as a dependency to the project?

At the moment I get this result:
[image]

And have the following setup:

[image]

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Got it working

What I did was use git to clone the woocommerce project

```
git clone https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/ temp
```

Then I copied the tests folder and put it inside my project. Then I kept making edits until it worked with my existing code.

Here is what my project looks like now:

[image]

I have a copy of the normal woocommerce project in my includes. The one without the tests, the one you can download from the WordPress plugin repository.

I copied the WooCommerce tests into the project, see folder wc_tests.

Here is what the tests/bootstrap.php file looks like

[image]

Note the last line that requires the wc_tests/bootstrap.php file.

I only made one change to the wc_tests file, I changed the plugin directory.

[image]

```
        $this->plugin_dir   = dirname( $this->tests_dir ) . '/includes/woocommerce';
```

Combined with a line of code out of screen, it makes the WC available for the project

```
        require_once $this->plugin_dir . '/woocommerce.php';
```

I'm probably doing some of this wrong, but it works.

Any further questions, tips or advice appreciated.